# Using different port for IKE2 VPN on Android

Tags: networking, vpn

My question is fairly simple: I would like to create an IKE2 VPN commection on stock Android11 but I don't want to use the default 500 or 4500 ports.

How can I do that?

I tried applying a colon then the port but it didn't work:
[image]

Is there a way with stock android11 to change the default port for a VPN connection?

Comment: I think the main problem is that VPN requires two ports, so specifying a port with server server address won't work as it is unclear which port you specify there. You may have to use  a VPN app that allows to create such a VPN profile.